# What uses more memory in c++? An 2 ints or 2 functions?

Tags: c++, class, memory, memory-management, methods

I am writing in c++ for the Nintendo DS (With 4MB of RAM). I have a button class that stores data like the x,y location and length. Which of the following would take less memory?

.

**Method 1**, class variables length, x, y, and halfPoint

```
Button::Button(int setX, int setY, int setLength)
{
    x = setX;
    y = setY;
    length = setLength;
    halfPoint = length/2;
}
//access variable with buttonName.halfPoint
```

**Method 2**, class variables length, x and y

```
Button::Button(int setX, int setY, int length)
{
    x = setX;
    y = setY;
    length = setLength;
}

int Button::getHalfPoint()
{
    return length/2;
}
//access variable with buttonName.getHalfPoint()
```

Any help is appreciated. (And in the real code I calculate a location much more complex than the half point)

Comment: Naively (without considering optimizations), a data member takes some number of bytes (possibly four for `int`) *per instance* of that class, while a function takes some number of bytes (look in the assembly output maybe?) *once*, for the whole program. However, details such as optimizations and function call overhead makes this naive analysis break down. So... measure! :)

Comment: one tip, if you're not modifying a parameter(SetX and SetY), you should pass them as const&(constant reference). that helps with performance

Comment: @blade: Not for small primitive types. That's called a pessimization.

Comment: maybe they are only 2 small data types, but as a matter of good practice, that's what i normally do according to mister bjarne stroupous, damm his last name is really tricky :)

Comment: @blade looks like you should read more [carefully](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#call-by-reference)

Comment: One thing that nobody pointed out yet, is that on the Nintendo DS you're dealing with multiple types of memory. Your code will exist in the cartridge ROM and will never be loaded into RAM. The only RAM method 2 will use is a bit of stack during the calculation of the halfpoint.

Comment: @pdw You brought up a good point, but I believe the entire program is ran in the RAM. I am able to take out the cartridge after loading the game in. Therefore it does not refer to the ROM (Aside from loading and saving).

Answer (score 2):

The `getHalfPoint()` method will take up less room if there are a lot of `Button`s.  Why?  Because member functions are actually just implemented by the compiler as regular functions with an implied first argument of a pointer to the object.  So your function is rewritten by the compiler as:

```
int getHalfPoint(Button* this)
{
    return this->length/2;
}
```

(It is a bit more complicated, because of name mangling, but this will do for an explanation.)

You should carefully consider the extra amount of computation that will have to be done to avoid storing 4 extra bytes, however.  And as Cameron mentions, the compiler might add extra space to the object anyway, depending upon the architecture (I think that is likely to happen with RISC architectures).

Comment: ARM is definitely RISC, so this could happen.  Really, the question remains (as it always is), speed or size?

Comment: This will be not repeatedly run. Only between menus. So speed is not at all an issue.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Still up to you, but I would just make a member function.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that depends!

The method code exists exactly once in memory, but a member variable exists once for each object instance.

So you'll have to count the number of instances you create (multiplied by the `sizeof` the variable), and compare that to the size of the compiled method (using a tool like e.g. objdump).

You'll also want to compare the size of your `Button` with and without the extra variable, because it's entirely possible that the compiler pads it to the same length anyway.

Comment: Please mention that it's much more complicated due to inlining and general optimization. While we can calculate the size of the button class, the amount of code each choice implies varies wildly with how it is used, where and how often, as well as the compiler options selected.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Good point. You may edit your comment in if you wish :-) Otherwise I think it's fine as a comment. Another point of interest is that in memory-constrained environments like this, the compiler can be passed a flag to optimize for size (`Os`) and disable inlining completely.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you declare the `getHalfPoint` method inside your class.  This will make the compiler *inline* the code.

There is a possibility that the code in the function is one assembly instruction, and depending on your platform, take the size of 4 bytes or less.  In this case, there is probably no benefit to have a variable represent the half of another variable.  Research "right shifting".  Also, to take full advantage, make the variable `unsigned int`. (Right shifting a signed integer is not defined.)

The *inline* capability means that the content of the function will be pasted wherever there is a call to the function.  This reduces the overhead of a function call (such as the branch instruction, pushing and popping arguments).  The reduction of a branch instruction **may** even speed up the program because there is no flushing of the instruction cache or pipeline.

Comment: They mentioned that they are doing something more complex than just division. If that's the case, I don't know if the method should be inlined.