# Memory usage of multiple constructors c++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, constructor, ram

I am coding in c++ for the Nintendo DS (With 4MB RAM). I've made a button class to display buttons in the UI [like I described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498642/what-uses-more-memory-in-c-an-2-ints-or-2-functions/). I have four separate constructor for convenience. I could condense all of them into one construct, but it would be inconvenient since I would be required to use all the arguments ever time it is constructed. My question is:

Will having multiple overloaded constructors take up more memory per object when the program is running, or will the compiler automatically strip the other 3 unnecessary constructors that each object doesn't need?

Any help is appreciated. Here are the arguments for the constructors with explanations:

```
Button::Button(int x, int y, const char * const label)
{
    //Set visibility to true as a default
    //Set length to String length
}

Button::Button(int x, int y, const char * const label, bool isVisible)
{
    //Set the length to the string length
}

Button::Button(int x, int y, const char * const label, int length)
{
    //set visibility to true as a default
}

Button::Button(int x, int y, const char * const label, int length, bool isVisible)
{
    //All the variables are specified using constructor
}
```

Comment: AFAIK an object only occupies memory for its data members, constructor is a method,i.e. a piece of code to initialize an object. So it does not matter how many constructors/methods are present, but source code size will be affected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I agree with the other answers vis., reducing the number of constructors will not save you anything in terms of object storage costs, you probably should do simply for convenience.

> I could condense all of them into one construct, but *it would be inconvenient* since I would be required to use all the arguments ever time it is constructed.

It doesn't have to be that way: this is what [default parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_argument) are for.  You prototype the constructor in a header like this:

```
class Button {
    Button (
        int x,
        int y,
        const char * const label,
        int length = -1, 
        bool isVisible = true
);
```

Notice the `=` after the last two parameters.  This means you do not have to supply these, and if you don't, that value will be used.  So:

```
new Button(1, 2, "hello");
new Button(1, 2, "hello", 5, false);
```

Are both fine.  You define the constructor normally, although the `length` field here is a bit special; if it could depend on the length of `label` *or* a user supplied value, you need to know the difference.  Thus in the initialization list, if the member field corresponding to the `length` arg is called `length` (not my favourite practice, but it doesn't matter here):

```
length (length > 0 ? length : label.length())
```

`length` will be initialization to the user arg if it is more than 0, and the default is -1, so if that arg is not supplied, `label.length()` will be used instead.

---

Note that the arguments must proceed in order, and so you should consider which are most likely to be used.  If in this case you want to allow either of the default params to be specified without the other, you would need two constructors.

Comment: What about new Button(1, 2, "hello", false);

Comment: Nope -- you have to preserve the order, so that's something to consider when you create it.  Going with the `length` example, since the default is in the header and the functionality is there, you can make using an argument < 0 = use label.length() an aspect of the API.  Or: put a `#define` or const value in the header and specify that instead (`Button(1, 2, "hello", Buttton::defaultLength, false`). But since default params are part of the language and pretty simple to understand, that might be excessive, *as long as you are ok committing the API to a "magic value"* (< 0).

Answer (score 4):

The number of constructors will not change the memory used per object. Adding a constructor does not have impact on the object size.

Comment: I would like to aim @RandomPerson323 at [my answer to his earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24498728/1830736).  The exact same thing happens with all member functions, including constructors.  That is, you have exactly one instance of each function per class.

Answer (score 4):

No the memory used for code is not per object but per class. It doesn't matter how many instances (objects) you have of a class, there will be only once copy of the code.

Only the non-static data members (the member variables) will be per instance.